# PHP image for each account

Tags: php, facebook, posts

I'm having facebook - like post system . My problem is that when the images are being retrieved , all the posts have the same picture as the person who is logged in and not that of the other person . Whereas in the database it is stored separately ...

```
//Defining 
$face=$FbWall->Gravatar($uid);
```

**FBwall**

```
public function Gravatar($uid) 
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Photo FROM users ");
    $pic="";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       $pic.= $row['Photo'] . ",";
    }
}
```

**Load Posts**

```
<?php } ?>
<div class="stbody" id="stbody<?php echo $msg_id;?>">
  <div class="stimg">
    <img src="profile_img/<?php echo $face;?>" class='big_face' alt='<?php echo $username; ?>'/>
  </div> 
  <div class="sttext">
  <?php
  if($userid==$uid)
  { ?>
    <a class="stdelete" href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id;?>" title='Delete Update'></a>
  <?php 
  } ?>
```

Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not familiar with the system you have in place but I suppose that $uid contains the user ID of the user that posted the message and that nexto to it you want to place their avatar.

In that case it's strange that you get filenames of ALL users from the users table, and such a comma separated list you are trying to add as image address.

My guess is that you are missing a WHERE in that SQL query. Something along the lines:

```
"SELECT Photo FROM Users WHERE uid='".$uid."'"
```

and than only apply that photo to the message. Also the above is considered a bad practice if the $uid is aquired from the user via let's say URL.